# How to diagnose a CentOS VPS not booting

Tags: centos, vps, boot

A few days ago (August 18), a friend accidentally rebooted his VPS in his admin panel (the VPS host is OVH). Problem is... it did never reboot. He didn't make any change for months on his VPS which is running a **Plesk** panel on **CentOS 6**.

Rescue boot (boot from a live CD) works well. I can mount partitions and see all the data. I tried to look for hints in `/var/log` but there are **no logs since Aug. 18**. There are no logs of my attempts to reboot it today.

Output of `tail -n 20 /var/log/messages`:

```
Aug 18 11:28:21 vpsXXXXXX proftpd[11413]: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY]) - FTP session opened.
Aug 18 11:29:22 vpsXXXXXX proftpd[11413]: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY]) - FTP session closed.
Aug 18 11:29:22 vpsXXXXXX xinetd[1020]: EXIT: ftp status=0 pid=11413 duration=61(sec)
Aug 18 11:38:09 vpsXXXXXX init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (2901) killed by TERM signal
Aug 18 11:38:09 vpsXXXXXX init: serial (ttyS0) main process (2902) killed by TERM signal
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX xinetd[1020]: Exiting...
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX acpid: exiting
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX init: Disconnected from system bus
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX console-kit-daemon[30927]: WARNING: no sender#012
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: received control channel command 'stop'
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: shutting down: flushing changes
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: no longer listening on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#53
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX named[376]: exiting
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX auditd[817]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Aug 18 11:38:11 vpsXXXXXX kernel: type=1305 audit(1503049091.989:89): audit_pid=0 old=817 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Aug 18 11:38:12 vpsXXXXXX kernel: type=1305 audit(1503049092.089:90): audit_enabled=0 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Aug 18 11:38:12 vpsXXXXXX kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Aug 18 11:38:12 vpsXXXXXX rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="847" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

Output of `cat /var/log/boot.log`:

```
                Welcome to CentOS
Starting udev: udevd[306]: can not read '/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules'
udevd[306]: can not read '/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules'

[  OK  ]
Setting hostname vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net:  [  OK  ]
Checking filesystems
Checking all file systems.
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/vda1
/dev/vda1: clean, 244942/1638400 files, 6238128/6553344 blocks
[  OK  ]
Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:  [  OK  ]
Mounting local filesystems:  [  OK  ]
ln: creating symbolic link `/dev/root': File exists
Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:  [  OK  ]
Entering non-interactive startup
ip6tables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:
Determining IP information for eth0... done.
[  OK  ]
Starting auditd: [  OK  ]
Starting portreserve: [  OK  ]
Starting system logger: [  OK  ]
Starting Dr.Web drwebd...
Dr.Web (R) daemon for Linux/Plesk Edition v6.0.2.1
Copyright (c) Igor Daniloff, 1992-2017
Doctor Web, Moscow, Russia
Support service: http://support.drweb.com
To purchase: http://buy.drweb.com
Key file: /opt/drweb/drweb32.key - Key file was not found! (No such file or directory)
A path to a valid license key file was not specified.
Plesk authorization failed: HTTP request error [7]
Error: Plesk Software not running.
Starting kdump:[  OK  ]
Starting system message bus: [  OK  ]
Mounting filesystems:  [  OK  ]
Starting acpi daemon: [  OK  ]
Retrigger failed udev events[  OK  ]
Starting sshd: [  OK  ]
Starting xinetd: [  OK  ]
Starting Courier IMAP authentication daemon: [  OK  ]
Starting Courier IMAP server: [  OK  ]
Starting Courier IMAP server with SSL/TLS support: [  OK  ]
Starting Courier POP3 server: [  OK  ]
Starting Courier POP3 server with SSL/TLS support: [  OK  ]
Starting psa-pc-remote: [  OK  ]
Starting php-fpm: [18-Aug-2017 11:16:04] WARNING: Nothing matches the include pattern '/opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf' from /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php-fpm.conf at line 119.
[18-Aug-2017 11:16:04] ERROR: No pool defined. at least one pool section must be specified in config file
[18-Aug-2017 11:16:04] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[18-Aug-2017 11:16:04] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[FAILED]
Starting psa... Starting sw-engine-fpm: [  OK  ]
                                                                      done
Starting xinetd service...                                            done
Starting sw-cp-server service...                                      done
Starting mysqld service...                                            failed
Trying to connect to MySQL... Failed to connect to MySQL: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
 Trying to start service mysqld... mysqld dead but pid file exists
Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]

WARNING!
Some problems are found during start(see log file: /var/log/plesk/install/plesk_12.0.18_reset_instance_data.log)

Continue...

 Trying to start service mysqld... mysqld dead but pid file exists
Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]

WARNING!
Some problems are found during start(see log file: /var/log/plesk/install/plesk_12.0.18_reset_instance_data.log)

Continue...

 Trying to establish test connection... ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104
failed

ERROR while trying to establish test connection
Check the error reason(see log file: /var/log/plesk/install/plesk_12.0.18_reset_instance_data.log), fix and try again

Starting named service...                                             done
Starting postgresql service...                                        not installed
Starting spamassassin service...                                      not installed
Plesk: Starting Mail Server...                                        done
Starting psa... Starting sw-engine-fpm:
                                                                      done
Starting sw-engine-fpm:
Starting nginx: [  OK  ]
Starting crond: [  OK  ]
initctl: Event failed
```

In this kind of situation where you can't see potential errors on a screen while the machine is booting, how can you diagnose and fix such problems?

Comment: This question should be asked of plesk support. Plesk isn't the kind of tool a professional Linux admin uses (and serverfaukt is for), it's the kind of tool one uses instead of putting in the effort to become proficient.  I did these problems by not using a 3rd party control panel.

Comment: @yoonix I doubt this is a Plesk problem. The VPS itself does not boot, I can't even ping it or use SSH.